# Comparing 1 column in 2 lines in Text file

Tags: python

How can I sort the file by (Line) and (point),Then check if "Line" column == next line "Line" column.

So Basically How to get the next value and compare it with current value After sorting by 2 keys.

I have this text file :

```
T,Swath,Line,Point,Idx,I,J,X,Y,Initial X,Initial Y,State
SP,1915,75501,64233.00,1,64233,75501,677912.500,3093762.500,677912.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64243.00,1,64243,75501,678037.500,3093762.500,678037.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64253.00,1,64253,75501,678162.500,3093762.500,678162.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64263.00,1,64263,75501,678287.500,3093762.500,678287.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64273.00,1,64273,75501,678412.500,3093762.500,678412.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64283.00,1,64283,75501,678537.500,3093762.500,678537.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64293.00,1,64293,75501,678662.500,3093762.500,678662.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64303.00,1,64303,75501,678787.500,3093762.500,678787.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64313.00,1,64313,75501,678912.500,3093762.500,678912.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64323.00,1,64323,75501,679037.500,3093762.500,679037.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64333.00,1,64333,75501,679162.500,3093762.500,679162.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64343.00,1,64343,75501,679287.500,3093762.500,679287.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64353.00,1,64353,75501,679412.500,3093762.500,679412.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
SP,1915,75501,64363.00,1,64363,75501,679537.500,3093762.500,679537.500,3093762.500,Theoretic
```

and this is my code:

```
Fin = open("1891_2150.txt" , "r")
for line in Fin:
      if line.startswith("T"): # to skip the header
         print ("\n ..\n")
      else:
         line2 = line.split(",")
         LineNb = int(float(line2[2]))
         PointNb = int(float(line2[3]))
         iGrid = int(line2[5])
         jGrid = int(line2[6])
         X = float(line2[7])
         Y = float(line2[8])
         iX = float(line2[9])
         iY = float(line2[10])
         if LineNb == next(LineNb):
             Dx = X - next(x)
             print (Dx)
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def convert(row): # convert each row to a list
    lst = row.split(",")
    return lst


with open("1891_2150.txt" , "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = content[1:] # remove the file head
rows = map(convert,content)

sorted(rows, key=itemgetter(2)) # sort by the Line


for key, group in groupby(rows, lambda x: x[2]):
    sorted(group,key=itemgetter(3)) #sort by the Point

for index in range(len(rows) - 1):
    if rows[index][2] == rows[index+1][2]:
        X = float(rows[index][7])
        X_next = float(rows[index + 1][7])
        print X - X_next
```

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len() .. I got this error

Comment: please post your TypeError traceback.  sorting by the point has been added

Comment: <module>
    for index in range(len(rows) - 1):
TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()

Comment: The type of `rows` should be `list`. Try to print out data of `rows`, and figure out what's going wrong

Comment: I add this `rows = list(rows)` after ` rows = map(convert,content) ` .. its working now many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the main objective of doing this is to detect when the values are the same in consecutive lines, you could compare the current value to the previous instead.

Also you might want to take a look at Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

```
import csv
import copy

columns = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    data_reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')
    previous_value = None
    columns_numbers = []
    for row in data_reader:
        if row[2] == previous_value:
            if len(columns_numbers) == 0:
                columns_numbers.extend([data_reader.line_num - 1, data_reader.line_num])
            else:
                columns_numbers.append(data_reader.line_num)
        else:
            if len(columns_numbers): columns.append(copy.copy(columns_numbers))
            columns_numbers = []
        previous_value = row[2]

    if len(columns_numbers):
        columns.append(copy.copy(columns_numbers))

print(columns)
```

The ouput of this code using your data sample as input would be:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

meaning that lines from 2 to 15 have the same value for the column `Line`.